# How to build a data source to access from flask app?

Tags: python, json, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a flask app, the purpose of which is to act as a dashboard.

I am fairly new to flask and python & have been trying to build by following online tutorials.

The basic front end is completed. Now, I need to provide a query from the front end which should match with a value in the data source.

My data should be in the following way:

```
Query1 -Functionality1 - int value
        Functionality2 - sub_FunctionalityA - int value
                         sub_FunctionalityB - int value
                         sub_FunctionalityC - int value
                         sub_FunctionalityD - int value
        Functionality3 - int value

Query2 -Functionality4 - int value
        Functionality5 - sub_FunctionalityE - int value
                         sub_FunctionalityF - int value
        Functionality6 - int value

Query3 -Functionality7 - int value
        Functionality8 - sub_FunctionalityG - int value
                         sub_FunctionalityH - int value
        Functionality9 - int value
```

(Sorry for the bad representation. Didn't know how else I could do better)

So, when I search for 'Query1' from GUI, I want a data source which would return the values under 'Query1'. I need to pass these 'int values' to a module which would return a string, that has to be printed in the web page.

I am not sure about the data source format to be used here. Based on what I searched, I could use database tables (I am very new to these concepts) or save these values in files or create a dynamic JSON file which can be parsed to get values.

Could someone help me by pointing to a procedure to start creating a data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and analyzing the available options, I have decided to use JSON format for storing the required data.